# Find collections intersection and exclude

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Has:

```
IEnumerable<int> oldValues; // Example: [1, 2, 3, 4]
IEnumerable<int> newValues; // Example: [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Need:

```
IEnumerable<int> removedValues; // Example: [1, 2]
IEnumerable<int> addedValues;   // Example: [5, 6]
```

Any ideas of nice LINQ solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) - this method returns those elements in first sequence that do not appear in second sequence.

```
IEnumerable<int> removedValued = oldValues.Except(newValues);
IEnumerable<int> addedValues = newValues.Except(oldValues);
```